# What is wrong with my code? I can't print a Barcode or a Qrcode

Tags: java, android, escpos

I have a problem with a print that is compatible with ESC/POS commands, I print successfully texts and lines.

this is my model from :
https://www.inputservice.com.br/leopardo-a8

and in the documentation, the print support:

**Códigos de Barras (Barcode translating): EAN8, EAN13, CODE39, ITF, CODEBAR, CODE128, CODE93, UPC-A, UPC-E, PDF417* e QR CODE.
Emulação (EMULATION): ESC/POS**

I don't understand that if I want to print a barcode I need to transform the bar in an image? or not?

I found a tutorial to print large images, this is the link :
http://new-grumpy-mentat.blogspot.com/2014/06/java-escpos-image-printing.html

I follow the tutorial but the image from my Qrcode or Barcode is not always good, see the picture :

[image]

Now see my code :

**PrintCommands.java**

package com.bravos.automap.Util.Print;

```
public class PrinterCommands {

    public static final byte HT = 0x9;
    public static final byte LF = 0x0A;
    public static final byte CR = 0x0D;
    public static final byte ESC = 0x1B;
    public static final byte DLE = 0x10;
    public static final byte GS = 0x1D;
    public static final byte FS = 0x1C;
    public static final byte STX = 0x02;
    public static final byte US = 0x1F;
    public static final byte CAN = 0x18;
    public static final byte CLR = 0x0C;
    public static final byte EOT = 0x04;

    public final static char ESC_CHAR = 0x1B;
    public final static byte[] LINE_FEED = new byte[]{0x0A};
    public final static byte[] CUT_PAPER = new byte[]{GS, 0x56, 0x00};
    public final static byte[] INIT_PRINTER = new byte[]{ESC_CHAR, 0x40};
    public final static byte[] SET_LINE_SPACE_24 = new byte[]{ESC_CHAR, 0x33, 24};
    public final static byte[] SET_LINE_SPACE_30 = new byte[]{ESC_CHAR, 0x33, 30};

    public static final byte[] INIT = {27, 64};

    public static byte[] FEED_LINE = {10};

    public static byte[] SELECT_FONT_A = {27, 33, 0};

    public static byte[] HEADER_FONT = {27, 33, 32};


    public static byte[] FONT_3X = {0x1D, 0x21, 0x21};
    public static byte[] FONT_2X = {0x1D, 0x21, 0x11};
    public static byte[] FONT_1X = {0x1D, 0x21, 0x00};

    // Bold
    public static byte FONT_BOLD = ((byte)(0x8 | SELECT_FONT_A[2]));

    // Height
    public static byte FONT_HEIGHT = ((byte)(0x10 | SELECT_FONT_A[2]));

    // Width
    public static byte FONT_WIDTH = ((byte) (0x20 | SELECT_FONT_A[2]));

    // Underline
    public static byte FONT_UNDER = ((byte)(0x80 | SELECT_FONT_A[2]));

    // Small
    public static byte FONT_SMALL = ((byte)(0x1 | SELECT_FONT_A[2]));


    public static byte[] SET_BAR_CODE_HEIGHT = {29, 104, 100};
    public static byte[] PRINT_BAR_CODE_1 = {29, 107, 2};
    public static byte[] SEND_NULL_BYTE = {0x00};

    public static byte[] SELECT_PRINT_SHEET = {0x1B, 0x63, 0x30, 0x02};
    public static byte[] FEED_PAPER_AND_CUT = {0x1D, 0x56, 66, 0x00};

    public static byte[] SELECT_CYRILLIC_CHARACTER_CODE_TABLE = {0x1B, 0x74, 0x11};

    public static byte[] SELECT_BIT_IMAGE_MODE = {0x1B, 0x2A, 33, (byte) 255, 3};

    public static byte[] SELECT_BIT_IMAGE_MODE_OFI = {ESC_CHAR, 0x2A, 33};;

    public static byte[] SELECT_BIT_IMAGE_MODE_V3 = {0x1B, 0x2A, 33, -128, 0};

    public static byte[] SELECT_BIT_IMAGE_MODE_V4 = {0x1B, 0x2A, 33, 127, 0};

    public static byte[] SELECT_BIT_IMAGE_MODE_V2 = {0x1B, 0x2A, 33};

    public static byte[] SELECT_BIT_IMAGE_MODE_V5 = {0x1B, 0x2A, 33, 124, 1};

    public static byte[] SET_LINE_SPACING_24 = {0x1B, 0x33, 24};
    public static byte[] SET_LINE_SPACING_30 = {0x1B, 0x33, 30};

    public static byte[] TRANSMIT_DLE_PRINTER_STATUS = {0x10, 0x04, 0x01};
    public static byte[] TRANSMIT_DLE_OFFLINE_PRINTER_STATUS = {0x10, 0x04, 0x02};
    public static byte[] TRANSMIT_DLE_ERROR_STATUS = {0x10, 0x04, 0x03};
    public static byte[] TRANSMIT_DLE_ROLL_PAPER_SENSOR_STATUS = {0x10, 0x04, 0x04};

    public static final byte[] ESC_FONT_COLOR_DEFAULT = new byte[] { 0x1B, 'r',0x00 };
    public static final byte[] FS_FONT_ALIGN = new byte[] { 0x1C, 0x21, 1, 0x1B,
            0x21, 1 };
    public static final byte[] ESC_ALIGN_LEFT = new byte[] { 0x1b, 'a', 0x00 };
    public static final byte[] ESC_ALIGN_RIGHT = new byte[] { 0x1b, 'a', 0x02 };
    public static final byte[] ESC_ALIGN_CENTER = new byte[] { 0x1b, 'a', 0x01 };
    public static final byte[] ESC_CANCEL_BOLD = new byte[] { 0x1B, 0x45, 0 };


    /*********************************************/
    public static final byte[] ESC_HORIZONTAL_CENTERS = new byte[] { 0x1B, 0x44, 20, 28, 00};
    public static final byte[] ESC_CANCLE_HORIZONTAL_CENTERS = new byte[] { 0x1B, 0x44, 00 };
    /*********************************************/

    public static final byte[] ESC_ENTER = new byte[] { 0x1B, 0x4A, 0x40 };
    public static final byte[] PRINTE_TEST = new byte[] { 0x1D, 0x28, 0x41 };



}
```

**SendPrint.java ( this example is from my EAN_13 code, but is the same thing, just change to QRCODE**

```
printerConstants = new PrinterConstants(mmOutputStream);


                mmOutputStream.write(PrinterCommands.INIT);
                mmOutputStream.write(PrinterCommands.ESC_ALIGN_CENTER);

                printerConstants.printString("TESTANDO A FUNÇÃO");

                mmOutputStream.write(PrinterCommands.FEED_LINE);
                mmOutputStream.write(PrinterCommands.FEED_LINE);

                printerConstants.setBold(true);
                printerConstants.printString("TESTANDO A FUNÇÃO");

                mmOutputStream.write(PrinterCommands.FEED_LINE);
                printerConstants.resetToDefault();

                String code = "7800000017106";
                MultiFormatWriter multiFormatWriter = new MultiFormatWriter();
                try {

                    BitMatrix bitMatrix = multiFormatWriter.encode(code, BarcodeFormat.EAN_13,200,80);
                    BarcodeEncoder barcodeEncoder = new BarcodeEncoder();
                    Bitmap bitmap = barcodeEncoder.createBitmap(bitMatrix);
                    int[][] pixels = getPixelsSlow(bitmap);
                    printImage(pixels);
                   // printPhoto(bitmap);

                } catch (WriterException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
```

Comment: Please give a [mcve] **in the question**.

Comment: I would suggest including the model of printer in your question, since you can side-step this issue completely on printers which support ESC/POS QR code commands.

Comment: I will edit now my question, plz some help

Answer (score 1):

---

> In Following Fucntion :
>
> 1. data : can be link or anything you want to put in QR-Code
> 2. size : howbig you want QR-Code to be

---

```
public static byte[] QRCodeDataToBytes(String data, int size) throws EscPosBarcodeException {

    ByteMatrix byteMatrix = null;

    try {
        EnumMap<EncodeHintType, Object> hints = new EnumMap<EncodeHintType, Object>(EncodeHintType.class);
        hints.put(EncodeHintType.CHARACTER_SET, "UTF-8");

        QRCode code = Encoder.encode(data, ErrorCorrectionLevel.L, hints);
        byteMatrix = code.getMatrix();

    } catch (WriterException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        throw new EscPosBarcodeException("Unable to encode QR code");
    }

    if (byteMatrix == null) {
        return EscPosPrinterCommands.initImageCommand(0, 0);
    }

    int
            width = byteMatrix.getWidth(),
            height = byteMatrix.getHeight(),
            coefficient = Math.round((float) size / (float) width),
            imageWidth = width * coefficient,
            imageHeight = height * coefficient,
            bytesByLine = (int) Math.ceil(((float) imageWidth) / 8f),
            i = 8;

    if (coefficient < 1) {
        return EscPosPrinterCommands.initImageCommand(0, 0);
    }

    byte[] imageBytes = EscPosPrinterCommands.initImageCommand(bytesByLine, imageHeight);

    for (int y = 0; y < height; y++) {
        byte[] lineBytes = new byte[bytesByLine];
        int x = -1, multipleX = coefficient;
        boolean isBlack = false;
        for (int j = 0; j < bytesByLine; j++) {
            StringBuilder stringBinary = new StringBuilder();
            for (int k = 0; k < 8; k++) {
                if (multipleX == coefficient) {
                    isBlack = ++x < width && byteMatrix.get(x, y) == 1;
                    multipleX = 0;
                }
                stringBinary.append(isBlack ? "1" : "0");
                ++multipleX;
            }
            lineBytes[j] = (byte) Integer.parseInt(stringBinary.toString(), 2);
        }

        for (int multipleY = 0; multipleY < coefficient; ++multipleY) {
            System.arraycopy(lineBytes, 0, imageBytes, i, lineBytes.length);
            i += lineBytes.length;
        }
    }

    return imageBytes;
}
```

---

[image]

> **I Prefer this [library](https://github.com/EmHaseeb/ThermalPrinterESCPOS) for printing over thermal printer**